# PNG images looking blurry on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Since I bought a new laptop (which I don't think is the problem behind this but in any case, it's a HP Pavilion Notebook 14), all the PNGs I upload to a certain site I'm part of are kind of blurry (not exactly blurry but kind of pixelated?). This doesn't seem to happen with other members' pictures, only mine are not showing up correctly.

In any case it's needed, I edit my pictures with Photoshop CS6 (downscaling them to 800x480 px and adding a Paint Daubs effect), then upload them on imgur and finally post them on the site.

Here's how the picture looks when previewing it:
[image]

And here's how the picture looks when posted:
[image]

I don't know if it's a notable difference, but I can assure you the second picture is not as sharp as it is on Photoshop, imgur or even when previewing before posting.

Anyone knows why it is happening? Is it a bug with Chrome (because the pictures are WAY better-looking on Firefox) or with the site?

Comment: Can it be that the maximum size for your image is exceeding what is allowed on the forum, and therefor it is shown smaller than it actually is? Eg: `<img width=800>http://.....</img>` If the image is resized, even by one pixel it will not look sharp anymore, but blurry.

Answer (score 1):

There is the same issue with a resolution in this forum posting, [Fix for blurry browser images in Chrome and FireFox](https://stickystatic.com/tech/browser-images-blurry)

> You know what the problem was? Apparently my font size in Windows
>   Control Panel under Display settings wast at “Medium 125%” and the
>   browsers suddenly started respecting the Operating System font size
>   and it was enlarging whole pages, images included which made them
>   blurry and pixelated. You can go change that back to 100% easily.
>
> So now I’m thinking that is probably happening to a lot of people and
>   they really don’t notice. So just go check your Control Panel Display
>   settings and make sure it says 100% then go view some webpages after.
>   They may seem smaller at first but they will be so much more clear and
>   laid out how the designer wanted you to see them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I checked my settings and the Display settings was already at 100%.